# Getting node-gyp dependent modules on windows without building

Tags: windows, node.js, node-gyp

There are many important **node-gyp**-dependent NodeJS modules, but to install them on windows requires a certain amount of software to be preinstalled (python, visual studio). It's crude and time-consuming solution:

1. Just to get proper Python + VS version for specific windows version is a challenge worthy of Sherlock Holmes skills
2. Installing whole IDE and Python and never use it, just to get module locally once? Crazy.
3. Distributing such nodejs apps may require consumer to have all that gyp-related bloatware to be installed, and that means loosing 99% consumers.

So what are possibilities of reducing this issue to zero?

Are there some services which provide pre-built to certain platform modules?

And why developers of those modules can't just distribute already built modules for major windows versions?

Answer (score 1):

There is a project addressing this issue called [node-pre-gyp](https://github.com/mapbox/node-pre-gyp). This does require the package developer to opt-in to using `node-pre-gyp` as well as figuring out how to host the binaries themselves somehow. But when it works it's pretty nice.

I have a similar project [electron-updater-tools](https://github.com/evolvelabs/electron-updater-tools) which supports [electron](https://github.com/atom/electron) compatible pre-built binaries.

There has been talk about node foundation adding some better support for this inherently (e.g. cross platform CI servers and binary hosting facilities) but the conversation is on-going.